# difference between concurrency and parallelism in multiple cores?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, computer-science, cpu-cores

I know the difference between parallelism and concurrency but want to know more about concurreny in multiple cores?

what is the difference between **concurrency** and **parallelism** in **multiple cores**?

can multiple threads run on multiple cores concurrently?

Comment: "can multiple threads run on multiple cores concurrently?" Yes. This is the purpose of having multiple cores. Actually they can even be executed in parallel. Note that multiple threads can be executed concurrently on modern hardware too thanks to pre-emptive scheduling and SMT.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the book "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams:

> Concurrency and parallelism have largely overlapping meanings with
> respect to multithreaded code. Indeed, to many they mean the same
> thing. The difference is primarily a matter of nuance, focus, and
> intent. Both terms are about running multiple tasks simultaneously,
> using the available hardware, but parallelism is much more
> performance-oriented. People talk about parallelism when their primary
> concern is taking advantage of the available hardware to increase the
> performance of bulk data processing, whereas people talk about
> concurrency when their primary concern is separation of concerns, or
> responsiveness. This dichotomy is not cut and dried, and there is
> still considerable overlap in meaning, but it can help clarify
> discussions to know of this distinction.

You second question is answered by @Jérôme in his comment.